# Angular Cli Asset folder not rendered in browser

Tags: angular, command-line-interface, assets

Assets Folder not rendered in browser.
try ng build in dist folder assets folder and files are available but however try ng serve the assets folder not rendered in browser

Comment: can you add the screenshot of the project structure?

Comment: Assets folder inside the src folder

Comment: How's the browser trying to find those files? (A browser's console screenshot perhaps?) Also, how are you building it? Are you using a different base-href than "/"?